# How to prevent spam inputs on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, spam-prevention

I would like to make a simple game, in which there is a single question, which will change when one of the users submit the correct answer.

But I need to prevent spam / meaningless inputs and bruteforce attacks.

An ActionScript 3 solution would also work.

I can figure that a solution would be collecting all inputs in a table with `timestamp`'s and check on every `insert`, however, I don't want to collect wrong guesses.

So, is there a ready-to-use JavaScript or any other way that controls maximum inputs per second? like captcha, but not captcha obviously. don't want to tire innocent visitors :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use jQuery to disable the button.

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $('#myButton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    setTimeout(unlockButton, 1000);
});                             

function unlockButton(){
    $('#myButton').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/D3zLf/

Answer (score 0):

Since Javascript can be blocked, you may be better off doing it in whatever language you are writing to the database with, for example if you were doing it in PHP:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($SESSION['answered'])){
        //Write to database
        $SESSION['answered'] = true;
    }
    else{
        //Display error message
    }
?>
```